# PostgreSQL - Alter Column used for a Fulltext Generated Column

Tags: postgresql

On PostgreSQL 13, I have a table define as such :

```sql
create table my_table (
   id serial8 primary key,
   title varchar(50),
   description varchar(512),
   french_vector_text tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('french', coalesce(title, '') || ' ' || coalesce(description, ''))) stored
);

create index IDX_FULL_TEXT on my_table using GIN(french_vector_text);
```

It works fine. However, when I try to alter a column used to generate the vector, like this

```sql
alter table my_table
alter column title type varchar(100);
```

I get an error telling me I can't alter a column used to calculate another, which is fair. I made it work by dropping the vector column with the index, altering the title column, and then recreating the column and index.

```sql
alter table my_table
drop column french_vector_text;

alter table my_table
alter column title
type varchar(100);

alter table my_table
add column french_vector_text tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('french', coalesce(title, '') || ' ' || coalesce(description, ''))) stored;

create index IDX_FULL_TEXT on my_table using GIN(french_vector_text);
```

Once again it worked fine, but in reality, the column is the aggregation of 7 columns, some with fairly large text, and the table may contain a couple ten thousand of records. So the operation took some time to complete.

Even if altering the schema isn't an everyday operation, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient solution that doesn't require dropping the column and fully recreates the index.

I thought about a trigger, but i would rather keep the generated column. So i tried creating an `IMMUTABLE` function as such :

```sql
create function my_french_vector(text_to_transform varchar) returns tsvector as $$ 
BEGIN   
    return to_tsvector('french', text_to_transform);
end 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
immutable;
```

And use it instead of the plain `to_tsvector`. But obviously, it doesn't work either as the column is still referenced.

As for my question, is there a way to alter a column used in a generated value, without having to drop it and recreate the whole thing after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a generated column at all, but define the index on an expression:

```
CREATE INDEX french_text_idx ON my_table
   (to_tsvector('french', coalesce(title, '') || ' ' || coalesce(description, '')));
```

Then modify the query to

```
... WHERE to_tsvector('french', coalesce(title, '') || ' ' || coalesce(description, ''))
             @@ to_tsquery('french', 'whatever')
```

and it will use the index.

When a new column is added, create a new index (`CONCURRENTLY`) that includes the new column, then change the query in your application, then drop the old index.

If you don't want to change the query in the application, define a view on the table that contains a calculated column with the indexed expression, then all you have to do is `CREATE OR REPLACE` the view.

Comment: I didn't think about the view, I will look into it, thanks.
Just a question, I initially used a generated column because I read [there](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH) that they were faster as there was no overhead due to calling `to_tsvector` at request time. Wouldn't the view + index be slower?

Comment: That depends on how many search results you have and what index scan type PostgreSQL chooses: if it has to "recheck" a lot of rows, it might be slightly slower. On the other hand, a stored column also needs to be calculated upon `INSERT` and it takes up space. You can test, but I don't think that the performance difference will be very big.